# Optimizing given assembly code for ARM using instruction sets

Tags: assembly, arm, micro-optimization

I was going through some past school assessments & came across this rather interesting question. The question asks to optimize said assembly code, I've written out the pseudocode in C (for reference).

The catch here is that my Professor said it's possible to write a **single** assembly instruction that will perform the same instruction as the original lengthy assembly code given. He also mentioned the code I wrote only offered marginal improvements in terms of optimization

Assembly Code to be optimized

```
    MOV r3, r4
    CMP r3, #0
    BLE .L2:
    ADD r3, r3, #1
    B .L3
.L2
    ADD r3, r3, #1
.L3
    SUB r3, r3, #1
    MOV r0, r3
```

Assembly Code I wrote

```
    MOV r3, r4
    CMP r3, #0
    BLE .L2:
    MOV r0, r3
.L2:
    ADD r3, r3, #1
```

Pseudocode written in C

```
r3 = r4;
if (r3 <= 0) {
    r3 = r3 + 1;
} else {
    r0 = r3;
}
```

Comment: Please check the manual at https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102374/0101/Program-flow---conditional-select-instructions
There is a (non-perfectly) matching instruction. I think your professor is ignoring the comparison.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: `csel` is ARM64.  ARM32 can predicate any instruction, like `addle r3, r4, #1`  But yeah, I don't think the *whole* thing can be done in one instruction, not if every effect on registers needs to be preserved as valuable.  In thumb mode, `cbz` or `cbnz` could also be useful to compare-and branch.  Without writing other regs, perhaps something with an arithmetic right-shift by 31 to get conditional behaviour based on the sign bit (becomes all-zeros or all-ones)

Comment: Your optimization is significantly better static code size (number of instruction bytes), and is less bad.  But you got the branch logic wrong in your C and asm translation - **your professor should have pointed out that you get different results**!.  Both sides of the `if` do `add r3, r3, #1` so there's no actual conditional behaviour.  Spoiler alert: https://godbolt.org/z/z9YMaMzfa. (But note that the compiler output doesn't write R3 or flags.  If you don't care about that, then yes most of this just optimizes away, and would only take a couple extra insns to fix.)

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: the querent's C version does compile to cmp / csel / cinc with clang for arm64, or to a branch with GCC (I didn't try a lot of different tuning options to see if it would prefer if-conversion on one.)  https://godbolt.org/z/bW7vndTd8.  Or for arm32, `movgt` / `addle`.  I used inline asm to get it to materialize the C vars into the right asm regisers.

Comment: Your C code isn't equivalent to the original assembly code. The original code doesn't make sense at all `mov r3, r4; mov r0, r4` would do the same. Maybe the professor meant that.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE hey your answer is correct (checked with my prof), could you post it as an answer & i'll accept it?